# Get the active jQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have some generic div's that is created several times on the screen, with no id. each form is converted to `dialog` with an "ok" button.

the "ok" is triggering some logic and is valid to the current dialog.

how can i access ONLY the inputs that in the active dialog?

```
<div class="ranges-editor">
    <input class="a" />
</div>

<div class="ranges-editor">
    <input class="a" />
</div>

$(".ranges-editor").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: "auto",
    height: "auto",
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Update",
            click: function () {
                alert($(".a").val());
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: What do you mean active? When do you want to use it?

Comment: when i'm clicking the "update" button, i want it to alert only the value of the input that is in the current dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if this is working?

```
$(".ranges-editor").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: "auto",
    height: "auto",
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Update",
            click: function () {
                alert($(this).find(".a").val());
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: `$(this)` is the `dialog` context? not the button's or function's?

Comment: if `$(this).dialog("close")` is working then `$(this).find(".a").val()` should also works, it is in the context of dialog.

Comment: o/c you are correct. missed it.. let's keep it between us.